# State propagation in hierarchical react views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, typescript, frontend

So I'm starting to learn Typescript+React in an industry setting (I've worked with a mixture of Coffee, Backbone, Marionettejs and a few others previously) and I was wondering what the idiomatic way to handle hierarchical views with respect to state transfer is.

For instance, let's pretend I'm attempting to make a card that will be placed on some dashboard. The card is composed of a header region, and a content region. The header region has a region for Title / subtitle, and a region for actions that can be done upon the card.

Now, lets say that there are a handful of objects from which the state necessary for rendering a card exists. What is the best way to pass down state to the children? For illustration lets say I have the following

```
class Report {
    const title: string;
    const subtitle: string;
    const data: any[];
          ...
}
```

1. Go the Backbone way I know of passing a large `options` object that just has everything that an entire hierarchy needs and let each child grab what it wants and append what it wants. In this case, that would be effectively flattening the stateful objects and grabbing the queries to shove into `props`. For example `<DashboardCard title={report.title} ... />`
2. Pass the objects with state down so that the children can grab what they need. `<DashboardCard report={ report }/>`
3. Not quite flatten everything but pass down groups of attributes bundled into the `props` that the children expect. E.g `<DashboardCard headerProps={ headerProps } ...>`. This seems like it breaks down pretty fast because then a parent needs to know the exact shape of every child node `props` object. `<DashboardCard headerProps={ } contentProps={ }/>`
4. Scrap the hierarchy notion altogether, and create simple base components and then views need to manually stitch them altogether. This makes passing state trivial because it's literally view -> all components, but then there is no nice abstraction that can help with adding new features to components and other things.

Maybe (probably) there is something fundamental that I am missing with frontend development and react in general.

Answer (score 0):

In the situation you are describing, I would lean towards passing down the necessary objects as props to the children (option 2). I would say that options 1 or 3 might be preferable if you have a large number of objects to pass down, and option 4 isn't too enticing due to the loss of abstraction as you mentioned.